# save items of list box into text file

Tags: c#, .net

my application just get the text from the clipboard and set it into a listbox
and I need to save the items of listbox for next lunch
I've used this code for that

```
StreamWriter SaveFile = new StreamWriter(sPath);
numlastline = listBox1.Items.Count-1;
SaveFile.WriteLine(listBox1.Items[numlastline]);
SaveFile.ToString();
SaveFile.Close();
```

but its only save the last clip to the text and delet the Previous ones

Comment: `but its only save the last clip to the text and delete the Previous ones` because you told the program to only save the last one. working as intended

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines(sPath, listBox1.Items.OfType<Object>().Select(item => item.ToString()));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using File.AppendText to append to the file:

```
using (StreamWriter SaveFile = File.AppendText(sPath))
{
  SaveFile.WriteLine("hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
SaveFile.WriteLine(listBox1.Items[numlastline]);
```

you pass only one element `listBox1.Items[numlastline]`.
To pass all the elements you may use a loop

```
StreamWriter SaveFile = new StreamWriter(sPath);
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
   SaveFile.WriteLine(item);
}
SaveFile.ToString();
SaveFile.Close();
```

Comment: `using (StreamWriter SaveFile = new StreamWriter(sPath)) {...}`: do not close `IDisposable` explicitly - `saveFile.Close();`

Answer (score 0):

You must loop through the items and write them all to the file. Also to eliminate file opening and closing I encourage the use of `using` which takes care of all that for you. Also, creating a `FileStream` first gives you more control over how to open your files.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```